# LTspice: Noise simulation AND AC analysis in one plot

Tags: spice, ltspice

Is it possible to run a noise simulation and an AC simulation independently from one another and
display the results in the same plot?

Or better, is there a way to determine the SNR  in one single plot?

Comment: [LTSpice noise sim tutorial](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1148) at about 5min shows how to turn gain trace on. Perhaps that's what you're looking for? You can also add custom math traces in LTSpice, so presumably you just add one which computs SNR from Vnoise out and Gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot display the results of different simulation types in the same graph.

However, you can export the numerical results of each of these individual plots to a .txt file and then graph them in another program. The link below shows how to export waveform data.

http://www.linear.com/solutions/1815

Comment: Neat, totally forgot about that option! Yeah, that's a nice approach!